# C++ what happens when `extern int * name` refers to a variable that doesn't exist, and then `name` gets accessed

Tags: c++, pointers, extern

I had an `extern unsigned int * name` in a .cpp and then I commented out the pointer (declared elsewhere) that it refers to. To my surprise, the program still runs without crashing and actually works as intended, and I'm sure that `name` is being dereferenced. So what exactly happens under the hood in this situation?

Comment: It should fail to compile. Thus you are probably running an old copy.

Comment: @Loki, typically it should fail to link

Comment: @Matt can you please give more info, what compiler are you seeing this with, are any libraries involved?  Also add compile and link commands

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either you are mistaken about `name` being dereferenced, or you somehow added a new `name` of the same type elsewhere.

Comment: @MattMunson - So, which was it? :)

Comment: Well I had added a new `name` as a member of a class and it was in thatclass.cpp where the extern line was. So apparently its valid to point extern to a member of a class (even though this doesn't tie it to any particular object member as far as I can see).

Comment: If you were using `name` in a member function, and you had a class member named `name`, it was using the class's `name` and not the global.

Comment: That's what I sort of figured. But then why did it not fail to link?

Comment: Why would it? If your program was using the member `name` and not the global `name`, what would fail to link?

Answer (score 4):

You are missing something, because the linkage process should fail in this case. It will be more clear what is happening if you provide any concrete compileable code example.